# How to Resolve the 'The Syntax for ')' is Incorrect' Error in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm getting the error: 'The syntax for ')' is incorrect.' in my DAX query. Kindly help me solve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y55pa.png)

I tried using a DAX formatter and consulted Stack Overflow to resolve this error, but the issue still persists.

Comment: You could try to delete the last one and also the opening parenthese in front of your measure’s name?

Comment: if you do something extra simple like counting the open parens and closing, you'll see that one is missing.

Comment: @Pieter I don't think this DAX will work even if you count open and closed parens .. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to solve a problem with a DAX formula. I recommend giving the following code a try:

```
(Orders last 90 days by frequency) =
VAR vLimInf = MIN(ProdFrequency[Inf])
VAR vLimSup = MAX(ProdFrequency[Sup])

RETURN
CALCULATE (
    /* Replace this line with your actual expression */,
    FILTER (
        VALUES('Product'[ProductName]),
        [Orders Last 90 Days] > vLimInf &&
        [Orders Last 90 Days] < vLimSup
    )
)
```

Make sure to replace the comment line /* Replace this line with your actual expression */ with your specific DAX expression that you want to calculate in this context. And certainly, it's a good practice to use a RETURN statement for every DAX variable.